# The questions of sentences using linking verbs

Tags: grammar

I understand that the word "look" in "He looks happy." is a linking verb. As "look" here can be replaced by "is"
My question is what is the correct question form of this sentence? 
Does he look happy? or Is he look happy? 
Thank you.

Comment: You understand incorrectly, I'm afraid. There are no "linking verbs" in English. There are auxiliary verbs, though, and _be_ is one, but _look_ is not one. "Linking verb" is a term made up by frustrated grammar teachers to explain away details they don't understand. The definition is confusing and hard to apply, as you've found. In this case, it is not true that "_look_ here can be replaced by _is_". If your textbook or your teacher uses the term, don't be surprised if you can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

"Does he look happy?" is the correct form.  If you were to use "is", the question would be, "Is he happy?"

Comment: A variant might be "Is he looking happy?"